# Jenkins: Build and Run Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am currently thinking about the potential solutions for building and running a Jenkins Maven project. I am a Jenkins Noob and what I currently think of is providing a Maven Plugin that runs the project right after the build and test phase. This feels wrong... .

So my basic question is, is it possible in Jenkins to configure a process to build a maven project and execute it right away and taking care for not interfering with it by starting another process and rebuilding it since a change arrived.

If this is possible it would ease the task by omitting the "Let's write a Maven plugin".

Comment: Just putted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you means by 'execute'? Your program is a jar? If you do have to deploy it, there is tools in Jenkins to deploy with the build phase. If not, I think you can always make a 'Post build' command like java -jar nameofprogram.jar

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins you can configure jobs to execute multiple Maven targets when the jobs are run. I don't know if this answers your question, but you should be able to accomplish what you want by using "post build steps" and trigger certain behaviour from there.

Comment: Both of your answers are good but JFP was faster and has the java command in it. (He wrote it as an comment first).